# Python/ Pycharm memory and CPU allocation for faster runtime?

Tags: python, performance, runtime

I am trying to run a very capacity intensive python program which process text with NLP methods for conducting different classifications tasks.

The runtime of the programm takes several days, therefore, I am trying to allocate more capacity to the programm. However, I don't really understand if I did the right thing, because with my new allocation the python code is not significantly faster.

**Here are some information about my notebook:**

I have a notebook running windows 10 with a intel core i7 with 4 core (8 logical processors) @ 2.5 GHZ and 32 gb physical memory.

**What I did:**

I changed some parameters in the vmoptions file, so that it looks like this now:

```
-Xms30g
-Xmx30g
-Xmn30g
-Xss128k
-XX:MaxPermSize=30g
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=20
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

**My problem:**

However, as I said my code is not running significantly faster. On top of that, if I am calling the taskmanager I can see that pycharm uses neraly 80% of the memory but 0% CPU, and python uses 20% of the CPU and 0% memory.

**My question:**

What do I need to do that the runtime of my python code gets faster?
Is it possible that i need to allocate more CPU to pycharm or python?
What is the connection beteen the allocation of memory to pycharm and the runtime of the python interpreter?

Thank you very much =)

Comment: How big is your project ..or is there just few files ?Pycharm keeps hashing each and every file which takes lot of memory

Comment: It is about 900 LOC, with different self-written feature extraction methods and supervised classifiers from different learning categories of sklearn including decision trees, linear SVC, Multilayer Perceptron and more.

Comment: Do you have professional license . Please do add a query to pycharm

Comment: I am using the community version. Sorry, what kind of query should I post?

Comment: how did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can not increase CPU usage manually. Try one of these solutions:

1. Try to rewrite your algorithm to be ***multi-threaded***. then you can use
   more of your CPU. Note that, not all programs can profit from
   multiple cores. In these cases, calculation done in steps, where the
   next step depends on the results of the previous step, will not be
   faster using more cores. Problems that can be vectorized (applying
   the same calculation to large arrays of data) can relatively easy be
   made to use multiple cores because the individual calculations are
   independent.
2. Use ***numpy***. It is an extension written in C that can use optimized
   linear algebra libraries like ATLAS. It can speed up numerical
   calculations significantly compared to standard python.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the number of CPU cores to be used by the IDE when running the active tasks (for example, indexing header files, updating symbols, and so on) in order to keep the performance properly balanced between AppCode and other applications running on your machine.
[ues this link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/how-to-adjust-cpu-cores-number.html#1568228b)